# Pushing to github repos as different users

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I figured out how to PULL from different repos as different users in Source Tree, essentially you just make sure your repo is something like

```
https://username@github.com/repo-name.git
```

That works great.  However, committing and pushing as a specific user seems to be a HUGE pain.  Below I've reproduced the method I currently use (and it does work) but I wish there was a way to do it natively in Source Tree.  Is there?

---

*This is Mac specific, but could probably be done fairly similarly on any *nix system.*

First you must be able to authenticate to Github via ssh.

1. Create new SSH key

   - **ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "other-gitub-email@domain.com"**
   - when prompted, save file to **/Users/yourname/.ssh/other-github-email**
2. Copy SSH key to github

   - **pbcopy < ~/.ssh/other-github-email**
   - log into other-github-email user on github
   - go to settings -> ssh keys -> add ssh key
   - cmd+v your key into the box
3. Create a config file to identify the new user on your local machine

   - **touch ~/.ssh/config**
   - edit that file and put the following in it:

     ```
     Host personalGithub
     Hostname github.com
     User yourusername
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

     Host other-github-email
     Hostname github.com
     User other-github-email
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/other-github-email
     ```
4. Add your new id to your current SSH session(s)

   - **eval “$(ssh-agent -s)”**
   - **ssh-add ~/.ssh/other-gitub-email**
5. Test your connection

   - **ssh -T git@github.com

Assuming that you can connect to github, you can now **pull** from git using SourceTree if you use this repo naming structure:
https://other-gitub-email@github.com/repo.git

However, to **push** or **commit** to it, you MUST do it from the command line.

1. Add your other-gitub-email id to your current SSH session(s)

   - **eval “$(ssh-agent -s)”**
   - **ssh-add ~/.ssh/other-gitub-email**
2. Test your connection

   - **ssh -T git@github.com**
3. Commit with the correct author specified (you may have to `git add filename` first)

   - **git commit --author=’other-gitub-email <other-gitub-email@domain.com>’ -m ‘commit message’**
4. Push

   - **git push origin master**
5. Or, push to a branch

   - **git push origin branchname:branchname**

---

As I said... the above steps do work, but it completely disrupts my workflow.  I would FAR rather do it with Source Tree.  Help?